# JohnTheRipper not working

Tags: john-the-ripper

I'm using this command to try to crack the hashes or the "contrasena" file and it doesn't do anything. It only says `using default input encoding` but nothing after.

```
john --wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt contrasena  > descifrado1

Using default input encoding: UTF-8
```

Comment: did you check the contents of the file `descifrado1`? Did you try running the command without piping the results to another file?

Comment: yep nothing seems to work

Comment: Does that mean that the file is empty?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the verbosity level of `john`?